# time source somescript.sh : time not displayed

Tags: linux, shell, unix, time, zsh

I'm trying to know how long a `source somescript.sh takes`.
But `time source somescript.sh` displays nothing.

I have no error but I may do something wrong because with a `time date` the time it takes to perform the `date` is displayed.

It works on sh but not on zsh (My default shell).

How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try timing how long the script takes to execute instead of how long it takes to source.

```
time ./somescript.sh
```

the time taken to source should be synonymous with this.